# How can I use a third-party API which has basic authentication (username, password) in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have one third-party API (a URL). To access that URL I have to give basic authentication which is *username* and *password*.

How can I get data from that API using basic authentication in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.2.1/user/authentication/) package. Something like:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```